# array of inappropriate type initialized from string constant

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct det{

    char fname[25];
    char lname[25];
    char sub[5];
    int marks[5];
};

int main(){

    int n, i, j;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Student Marklist","a");
    struct det st[60] = {{"Bangla","English","Math","Science","ICT"}};

    printf ("\n Number of students : ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){

        printf ("\n Marklist of student %d\n\n",i + 1);

        for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
            printf (" %s Marks : ",st[i].sub[j]);
            scanf ("%d", &st[i].marks[j]);
            fprintf (fp, " %s : %d\n", st[i].sub[j], st[i].marks[j]);

        }

    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;

}
```

"array of inappropriate type initialized from string constant "Error on  12th line. What to do?

Comment: Your first element of the `st` array contains five elements. Your struct only takes four.

Comment: `{fname:"Bangla",lname:"English",sub:"Math",marks:{"Science","ICT"}!!}`

Comment: This isn't even close. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: `char sub[5];` --> `char sub[5][16/* The maximum size of the subject name + 1.  */];`

Answer (score 0):

It expects the initialisation data like `{ { fname, lname, sub, marks }, {fname, lname, sub, marks }, ... }`. Example: `{ {"Fname1", "Lname1", "Phys", { 0,1,2,3,4} }, {"Fname2", "Lname2", "Math", { 5,6,7,8,9} }, ... }` assuming `sub` is a string

```
struct det{

    char fname[25];
    char lname[25];
    char sub[5];
    int marks[5];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct det st[60] = { {"Fname1", "Lname1", "Phys", { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 } }, { "Fname2", "Lname2", "Math", { 5,6,7,8,9} } };
```